# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found

Tags: magento2, php

Someone changed my php version for my magento 2 website to 5.6 and I changed it back to 7.0 and now I'm getting this error when I try to run the major magento commands such as compile and system:upgrade

> > The file "/var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Composer/Console/ApplicationFactory.php"
> >     cannot be deleted
> >     Warning!unlink(/var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Composer/Console/ApplicationFactory.php):
> >     Permission denied#0
> >     /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(405):
> >     Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/var/www/vhosts...')
> >     1 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403):
> >     Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/vhosts...')
> >     2 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403):
> >     Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/vhosts...')
> >     3 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/CompilerPreparation.php(68):
> >     Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/vhosts...')
> >     4 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(74):
> >     Magento\Setup\Console\CompilerPreparation->handleCompilerEnvironment()
> >     5 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
> >     6 {main}
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/bin/magento:31 Stack trace:
>   0 {main}   thrown in /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/bin/magento on line 31
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/bin/magento:31 Stack trace:
>   0 {main}   thrown in /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/bin/magento on line 31

What can I do to fix this error?

UPDATE: Here are the results when I run rm -rf var

```
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/setup.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/webapi_rest.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/frontend.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/global.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/adminhtml.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/crontab.ser’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘var/di/webapi_soap.ser’: Permission denied
```

Comment: have you tried clearing var/generation and tring again ? also check file permissions and owner of that folder

Comment: remove var folder and try to  run compile command.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar I tried clearing the var/generation but I get a bunch of access denied errors and I have given myself full permission for that folder

Comment: @Rakesh I have always been able to run this as my normal username in ssh but it suddenly doesn't work anymore. I confirmed that sudo works but I need to figure out the root issue as to why my normal account no longer works to delete that folder

Comment: share the "bunch of access denied errors " sample

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar I updated my question to include the sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with Plesk it's from the Magento script itself. Whoever wrote it clearly has no idea of PHP OOP. Sorry but it's true.

There's nowhere to be found an "use" keyword in the script but you can clearly see that he's trying to use

```
  Cli
```

class without specifying the namespace. That's the whole error if you change it to

```
  Magento\Framework\Console\Cli
```

it will work.

Change the `bin/magento` shell file from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
    exit(1);
}

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
    exit(Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
    exit(1);
}

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
    exit(\Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```

Take a look at the exit at the end...

Sorry if I offended somebody ;]

Comment: Namespaces != OOP per se. This apparent bug was fixed in Magento 2.2. It is indeed a shameful one, like Magento 2 overall :)

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you are using the correct `php` version.
You must use the version that you used to install composer packages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct permission of edit and delete to **var** folder of Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

***I think , you are using plesk webhosting***

*So,Go for this path first.*

> cd /opt/plesk/php
>
> ls

check PHP version is available or not.

*IF exist..run below command*

> /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento

Then run *Magento Cli* command as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well.

Here is the steps I followed to correct the issue:

1. Delete var/cache and var/generation folders.
2. Check that you are running a supported php version.
3. Made sure the apache process can write and read to the var/ folder.
4. If it's still failing and you haven't changed any server or permission setting, move you app/code folder to a temp location and run the command again. The same error will display if you have a serious module issue. (This was my issue)

Answer (score -1):

am running kali linux debian gnome core

```
Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xsl.ini with new version
Setting up php-xml (1:7.2+62) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.9-1) ...
$ sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend.php on line 79#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'The each() func...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 79, Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(79): each(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(183): Zend_Cache_Backend->setDirectives(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Cache/Core.php(138): Zend_Cache_Core->setBackend(Object(Cm_Cache_Backend_File))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(111): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->setBackend(Object(Cm_Cache_Backend_File))
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(154): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(84): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default')
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config')
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(66): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load('global::DiConfi...')
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(77): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global')
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array)
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array)
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(362): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->initObjectManager()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->getObjectManager()
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#18 {main}

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/bin/magento:31
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/bin/magento on line 31
```